# Using Eigen LIbrary with CBLAS

Tags: blas, eigen3, cblas

I know that I can ask Eigen to use a Blas library by defining the variable "EIGEN_USE_BLAS". I have a very efficient CBLAS implementation available on my system. Is it possible to make Eigen to use that CBLAS library?

Comment: If you toss in a little more details, one might be able to help. OS, which "efficient library", ...

Comment: cblas is usually just a tiny wrapper over a  BLAS, are you sure you're not in that case? And what is this super fast CBLAS?

Comment: @ggael This is a vendor supported library. Unfortunately only the CBLAS version was given!